# Meaning of English words.

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, british-english

Why do (British) English words have so many meanings? Why? What is reason? Some words (verbs, nouns etc.) have more than three meanings and some have more than **ten** meanings. What on earth. Does it exist only in English? How do English speakers know what someone means? Why some words are *the verb*, *the adjective*, *the noun* and more at the same time ?

Thanks for explanation.

Comment: This question doesn't belong here, it belongs on http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/. Weirdly, my only flag option is to move it to ell.meta.

Comment: It's pretty much the same in Russian.

Comment: I know for sure that in German, Spanish, and Japanese there are words with multiple meanings, so I suspect many languages are like this to some extent.

Comment: [Polisemy](http://www.google.com/url?q=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjzpfOQ2O_SAhVWVWMKHVQeCSQQFggPMAE&sig2=jq6aI90NQX1SLeMPSSftpA&usg=AFQjCNGcJY8K-F9Vi81uG7YxjJxLqeOjBA) also does exist in my native language(Malay).

Comment: Have you ever looked up the definition for "set"? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set

Comment: @Shufflepants :-) Great. [link](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have_1?q=have) is also good. :-)

Comment: @Choirbean That's [meta-tag:status-bydesign]; flag for moderator attention if you want it moved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like all languages, English was not designed: it has evolved. If we could start again, we could in principle do a better job, but attempts to do so (for example, Esperanto) are technically perfect but never catch on.

English is not the only language to have words with multiple meanings: just think how many ways you can use the word [správa](http://slovnik.azet.sk/synonyma/?q=spr%C3%A1va) in your own language. Indeed, in most languages there are tens of meanings for each proposition. You are unaware of the sheer variety of meanings in your mother language: you are so accustomed to it that you don't think about it. It's only when you start to learn another language that you realise how complicated it is.

How do we know what somebody means? We identify the form (adjective, noun, verb) by the grammatical context. We identify the specific meaning by the semantic context. It's not perfect, but it works pretty well most of the time.

Comment: Interesting, I had to look up správa.  Apparently it can mean anything from "a message" to "flimsy".

Comment: @Andrew "správa" is only "a message" -- see [link](https://slovniky.lingea.sk/Anglicko-slovensky/message?) You're right.